# Pandas won't load first of the columns in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I started working through the book *Doing Data Science* and I'm doing the first exercise in Python. They provide data here: [data for book](https://github.com/oreillymedia/doing_data_science)

I do this:

```
ny = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('/path/nyt1.csv', sep=',')
```

I get 4 columns, the first is missing and there should be 5! If I open the file in LibreOffice, I get 5 columns.

I tried changing parameters a bit, but can't figure out what's going on.

Data looks like this:

```
"Age","Gender","Impressions","Clicks","Signed_In"
36,0,3,0,1
73,1,3,0,1
30,0,3,0,1
```

Comment: You'll need to show a sample of the data.

Comment: try pd.read_csv('/path/filename.csv')

Comment: @BrenBarn. Added! Dumb of me not to have put it there to begin with ...

Comment: @Plug4: thanks a lot, it worked! I don't understand though, is your way the preferred way?

Comment: Yes, `DataFrame.from_csv` is in practice deprecated (but not yet officially). It has slightly different defaults as `read_csv`, of which one is to set the first column as the index by default. See https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4191

Comment: Ah, I sort-of thought that was as index, but wasn't sure. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `read_csv`:

```
ny = pd.read_csv('nyt.csv')
>>> ny.head()
   Age  Gender  Impressions  Clicks  Signed_In
0   36       0            3       0          1
1   73       1            3       0          1
2   30       0            3       0          1
3   49       1            3       0          1
4   47       1           11       0          1
```

Answer (score 1):

@Plug4 solved the issue, if I import with `pd.read_csv('/path/filename.csv')` it works.